# Is it possible to get OpenCL on Windows Linux Subsystem?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, opencl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'v been trying for the past day to get **Tensorflow** built with **OpenCL** on the Linux Subsystem.

I followed [this guide](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl). But when typing `clinfo` it says

> Number of platforms                               0

Then typing `/usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info` gives me

> OpenCL error -1001: Unable to retrieve number of platforms. Device Info:
>    Cannot find any devices on the system. Please refer to your OpenCL vendor documentation.
>    Note that OPENCL_VENDOR_PATH is not defined. Some vendors may require this environment variable to be set.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it even possible to install OpenCL on  Windows Linux Subsystem?

**Note:**
I'm using an `AMD R9 390X` from `MSI`, `64bit Windows Home Edition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a Microsoft representative in [this forum post](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/16108045-opencl-cuda-gpu-support), Windows Subsystem for Linux does **not** support OpenCL or CUDA GPU programs, and support is not currently planned. To experiment with TensorFlow/OpenCL it would probably be easiest to install Linux in a dual-boot configuration.

Comment: This answer it (at least partially) outdated. Please check: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Answer (score 6):

With the launch of WSL2, CUDA programs are now supported in WSL ([more information here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html)), however there is still no support for OpenCL as of this writing: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6951.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Intel OpenCL SDK for the CPU, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers.

Comment: It looks like [the Intel OpenCL SDK requires kernel patches](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_linux_driver), which aren't possible on Windows Subsystem for Linux as [the kernel source is not available](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/178).